# Link to page with posts of specific type

Tags: php, css, javascript, html

This might be a stupid question, but I am having difficulty finding an answer on google. I have a section of my site that loads 4 divs with a post title, excerpt and 'read more' link to the full post. Under these 4 divs I have 3 links, one is "View All". It needs to load a page of all the posts with that type. Could anyone give me any advice on how to accomplish this? Thanks!

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="news-events group">
  <div class="col1">
    <h1>News & Press Releases</h1>

    <?php query_posts('post_type=issues&posts_per_page=4'); ?>
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full_size' );
      $url = $thumb['0']; ?>

      <div class="post-container container-<?php echo $i; ?>" style="background-image:url('<?=$url?>');">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More ></a>
      </div>
      <?php $i++ ?>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <div class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <a href="#"><li>View All</li></a>
        <a href="get-involved"><li class="gi">Get Involved</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Next Page</li></a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, never use `query_posts`, use [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to create additional queries.

When you [register your post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), set `has_archive` to `true`, or a string which will be the URL slug for your post type archive.

You can then use [`get_post_type_archive_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_archive_link) to output the URL to your post type archive.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'issues' ); ?>"><li>View All</li></a>
```